# Hard resetting an STM32

Tags: stm32, reset

My STM32 is behaving weirdly, to say the least. What is the best way to "hard reset" an STM32? I've tried pressing the "reset" button, and unplugging/replugging everything, but it seems like the weirdness remains.

How can I make a hard reset to restore all the registers and all the memory back to their reset values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything else except flash and EEPROM should reset on reset or power off. Hard to say what is your exact problem unless you specify what kind of "weirdness" it is doing.

Comment: It's probably the Flash that I want to reset, as I'm loading the executable onto Flash, and reading from there. How can I clear the Flash?#

Comment: You need to erase it. The software you are using should have an option to erase the flash.